# convert file to base64 function output

Tags: vb.net, file, base64

```
Public Function ConvertFileToBase64(ByVal fileName As String) As String

    Dim ReturnValue As String = ""

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(fileName) Then
        Using BinaryFile As FileStream = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)
            Dim BinRead As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(BinaryFile)
            Dim BinBytes As Byte() = BinRead.ReadBytes(CInt(BinaryFile.Length))
            ReturnValue = Convert.ToBase64String(BinBytes)
            BinaryFile.Close()
        End Using
    End If
    Return ReturnValue
End Function
```

The questions I want to ask:

1. I want the output that is I want to convert a text file "C:\Users\user\Desktop\rats\test\test.txt"
   to base64
2. I was unable to get any output when i converted "test.txt" to base64
3. I use filename="textbox1.text" to add my "test.txt"

Comment: What is the problem? Does it return Nothing? Did you  tried to put breakpoint inside the function to see what is going on? The most probable answer is that the path is wrong (you give a filename only and a full path is required).

Answer (score 18):

```
   Public Function ConvertFileToBase64(ByVal fileName As String) As String
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName))
    End Function
```