# VB Hex to DocX Object

Tags: vb.net

I have a selection of docx files stored as blob data in hexadecimal, I need to retrieve these so I can access the text within.

So far, I have converted the hex to string format with the following:

```
Dim blob = BLOB DATA
Dim con As String = String.Empty
For x = 2 To st.Length - 2 Step 2
    con &= ChrW(CInt("&H" & st.Substring(x, 2)))
Next
```

However, if I then save the output from this as a .docx the file will not open because it is 'corrupt'. I presume that is why when I load this string into a memorystream and then try and use Novacode.DocX.Load(memoryStream) it gives me a similar corruption error.

I have tried splitting to byte array in two fashions, both give me different results.

```
System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(hex)
```

I have also tried.

```
Public Function HexToByteArray(hex As String) As Byte()
    Dim upperBound As Integer = hex.Length \ 2
    If hex.Length Mod 2 = 0 Then
        upperBound -= 1
    Else
        hex = "0" & hex
    End If
    Dim bytes(upperBound) As Byte
    For i As Integer = 2 To upperBound
        bytes(i) = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16)
    Next
    Return bytes
End Function
```

I then tried converting them both to a memory stream and using them to create a DocX object like so:

```
Dim doc As DocX = DocX.Load(New MemoryStream(bytes))
```

Comment: Please show both encode and decode methods.  Any reason you are using hex and not binary stream => base64 and back again?

Comment: docx is not a text format, it's a binary format. Thus, converting it to a string is just plain wrong. Your end result needs to be a byte array. I have flagged your question as a duplicate of a question which addresses exactly that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a Hexidecimal string to a Byte Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970436/how-do-i-convert-a-hexidecimal-string-to-a-byte-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert file to base64 function output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739264/convert-file-to-base64-function-output)

Comment: @SamMakin I don't have any control over encoding, I am just trying to decode these.

Comment: @Heinzi Thank you for linking that hex to byte array, however my hex isn't hyphen delimited. It's continuous.

Comment: @JacobMason: I see. Then don't split on `-`, [split on the length of 2 instead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8774392/87698).

Answer (score 0):

docx is not a text format, it's a binary format. Thus, converting it to a string is just plain wrong. Your end result needs to be a byte array.

Knowing that, your problem can be split into two simpler problems:

1. Split your hex string into strings of two characters each. See this SO question for details (or keep your existing loop, which is perfectly fine):

   [How to split a string by x amount of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8774392/87698)
2. Convert those "small" strings, which contain the hexadecimal representation of a byte, into bytes. See this SO question for details:

   [How do I convert a Hexidecimal string to a Byte Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14970436/87698)

Combining those two solutions is left as an exercise to the reader. We don't want to spoil all the fun or ruin the learning experience. ;-)

Comment: One last question, the 0x in front of the hex. It seems to be causing some issues, should I ignore it?

Comment: It's now converted to a byte array, however it is corrupt. I have tried file.writeallbytes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @JacobMason: Then the encoding might not be as simple as you think it is. I would suggest a binary compare of the resulting (decoded) file with the original file to find out where the differences are. Or double-check with the person who wrote the encoding code.

Comment: If we could see how the file was encoded we might be able to recreate the problem.....  and actually help....  It should *really* just be a case of reversing the operation.